# How to deal with error "Request method 'GET' not supported"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to implement deletion of a entity from a list view. And I faced this problem. Can you explain me, what is the problem and how can I ovrcome it?

The controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteComment/{commentId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteComment(@PathVariable int commentId, BindingResult result, Model model){
{
    Comment deletedComment = commentService.findCommentByID(commentId);
    if (deletedComment != null) {
         commentService.deleteComment(deletedComment);
    }

     return "refresh:";
}
```

Do I need to specify 'Get' method, if I'm dealing with list-view (and I see the whole list). If I need, what code should I place there. I have no any ideas...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in button type attribute.

If You have HTML button `type="submit"`  then Your service can be only `RequestMethod.GET`. When You change to `RequestMethod.POST` then You have "Request method 'GET' not supported".

SOLUTION: Change attribute in button tag to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `method = RequestMethod.POST` you are essentially saying that the `deleteComment` method should be called only for `POST` and for a path `/deleteComment/{commentId}`. If you want it to accept requests for GET also, you can just remove the method or accept GET also this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteComment/{commentId}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
```

You may also want to explicitly specify the name of the variable to bind to the commentId path variable this way:

```
public String deleteComment(@PathVariable("commentId") int commentId, BindingResult result, Model model){
```

Comment: Though, note that a GET shouldn't have side-effects. It should be safe to repeatedly GET a URI without any effect on the server. It should be safe to pre-emptively GET something as it seems likely a user will want to GET it later, and the entity returned will already be in cache, and so on.

Comment: But, why do I need the 'Get' method? I have all information from my list and I want to delete an item from this list. I can ee all the items, so'GET' part should be performed already.... or am I'm horribly mistaken?

Comment: You can map the same URL to multiple methods in your controller by specifying whether the method responds to a GET, POST, PUT, etc. Your code is telling Spring to only trigger that method when it receives a URL using a POST.